# Why does the "locals" function in Python output a global variable?

Tags: python, function, variables, global, local

```
y=3
class A:
    x = 1
    print(locals())
    print()
    print(globals())
print(globals())
print()
print(locals())
```

Why does the last line for `locals()` include the variable `y` even if it is global?

Comment: You're not in a function, so there is no local scope. `locals()` is `globals()`

Comment: There's no *distinct* local scope. "Local" is a relative term.

Answer (score 4):

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#locals):

> Note that at the module level, `locals()` and `globals()` are the same dictionary.